# Сonnecting a phone via smb to a laptop

Tags: java, android, jcifs

My laptop and phone are connected to wi-fi. There is a network folder on the laptop. To connect, I use the following code:

```
String URL = "smb://" + SERVER_ADDRESS + "/" + SHARED_FOLDER_NAME + "/" + FILE_NAME;
authentication = getPasswordAuthentication(null, null);
SmbFile dataFile = new SmbFile(URL, authentication);

private NtlmPasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(String user, String login)
{
    return (user != null && login != null)
            ? new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(user + ":" + login)
            : new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, null, null);
}
```

SERVER_ADDRESS is the ip address. My PC is 192.168.1.57, laptop is 192.168.1.36.

This code works correctly with my pc, but for some reason it doesn’t on the laptop:

```
jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect: 0.0.0.0<00>/192.168.1.36
W/System.err: jcifs.util.transport.TransportException
W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

I know for sure that the local folder on the laptop is configured correctly, since the standard file manager on my phone connects perfectly to the laptop and sees the folders I need.

Comment: Please tell both Windows versions.

Comment: windows 10 pro, the same versions on pc and laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I forgot that I turned on SMB1 support on my PC.

*Control panel -> Programs-> Programs and components -> Enable or disable components -> SMB 1.0 / CIFS File Sharing Support*